# Qt - Creating PDF file

Tags: qt, pdf

I want to create a PDF-file in Qt console application. But file size of created file is 0B and I can't open it.
The same code in GUI application works. Where is the difference between code in console and gui application? What should I do to make the code working in console application?
Thanks for help in advance!

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString html = "<h1>Hi!</h1>";

    QTextDocument document;
    document.setHtml(html);

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

    document.print(&printer);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it's working.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString html = "<h1>Hi!</h1>";

    QTextDocument document;
    document.setHtml(html);

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

    document.print(&printer);

    return a.exec();
}
```

so it looks like you have just to change the `QCoreApplication` by `QApplication`.

Comment: This works? I attempt to throw this in an embedded application without display, and all I ever get is "EGLFS: Failed to open /dev/fb0" ??

Comment: It works on a desktop. On embedded you must have a frame buffer "/dev/fb0" and the right to access it. Are you sure about it?